# Creating a CSS pentagon shape

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a pentagon shape in CSS but there's about a 1 pixel-wide gap across the middle vertices:

```
.shape-pentagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 5.4rem;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-width: 5.0rem 1.8rem 0rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: $primary transparent;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: -8.5rem;
    left: -1.8rem;
    border-width: 0rem 4.5rem 3.5rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent $primary;
  }
}
```

[image: pentagon]

I can't seem to nudge the attributes just enough to fix this. Does anyone have a prettier pentagon or a fix to share?

Comment: Which browser is giving you issues? I'm checking the latest Firefox/Chrome on Mac and the pentagon looks solid.

Comment: Looks great on Chrome/Firefox for Windows for me. Looks like the exact same properties used by [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) as well.

Comment: This is probably related to sub-pixel rendering and your use of relative sizing. In Safari, I see it looks solid until I start playing with the text size (note: not zoom size, which also looks solid) and then I'm able to re-create the gap.